# MSXML string-compare problem

Tags: xml, msxml, xpath

Can someone please explain why this JavaScript code outputs zero instead of one?  Also, when elements //e[2] and //e[3] are swapped then it works, why?

```
doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
doc.loadXML(
"<r>               " +
"   <e id='a'>     " +
"      <e id='b'/> " +
"      <e id='c'/> " +
"   </e>           " +
"</r>              ")
doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ms='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'");
WScript.Echo(doc.selectNodes("/r/e[ms:string-compare(e/@id,'c','en-US', 'i')=0]/@id").length);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `count(/r/e/e[@id!='c'])`?

Comment: That is strange, but WScript.Echo(doc.selectNodes("/r/e[e/@id='c']/@id").length); works though.

Comment: @Alejandro and @Samuel Zhang: I updated the question and the xpath.  I want to do a case-insensitive search but it appears the string-compare function is buggy.  I didn't add the third and forth parameters originally because it does not work either way and I wanted to keep the sample code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please explain why this
>   JavaScript code outputs zero instead
>   of one? Also, when elements //e[2] and
>   //e[3] are swapped then it works, why?

Because the firm of your extension function is

```
number ms:string-compare(string x, string y, [,string language _
                                             [,string options]])
```

So, the `e/@id` inner most expression evaluated to a node set is cast to string taking the first node in the node set.

Without extension, you could use:

```
/r/e[e/@id[translate(.,'C','c')='c']]/@id"
```